# Public Symbol xml declared here is not defined error in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
Error:(675, -1) android-apt-compiler: [Ghost] F:\projects\Ghost\res\values\public.xml:675: error: Public symbol xml/ghostwidget declared here is not defined.
```

Hello, while compiling a project am getting this error although this file is present in layout and layout-v21 and can't seem to find out what's wrong with it. Please help.

here is a screenshot of my public xml [public xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8846U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You must have already used the identifier(The name) somewhere else.